# How to use JUnit 5 @Tag with IntelliJ and Maven

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit5

I would like to use the `@Tag` available in JUnit 5 in order to easily filter my tests.

I have found in [this blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/08/using-junit-5-in-intellij-idea/) input from September 2016 that IntelliJ was not supporting `@Tag`. Not sure what the current status is though.

Also, I am very new to using Maven but I have tried modifying the POM file in order to filter tests when executing `mvn test` in a command prompt. No luck.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can you provide an error or description? Maybe add the relevant parts of your pom file and an example of your tests (only relevant parts)

Answer (score 3):

Now it is possible with Intellij IDEA 2018.1, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50958900/4071001) for details (including screenshot).

---

Also, you can see [Build Support with Maven](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven) in JUnit official documentation for a proper configuration of `maven-surefire-plugin`. The section [Filtering by Tags](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven-filter-tags) can be especially useful to filter tests by tags.

> Example *(excluding all tests with the "**integration**" tag)*:

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <excludeTags>integration</excludeTags>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
                ...
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I found: changing the JUnit versions in the POM file from ...

```
<junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0-M2</junit.jupiter.version>
<junit.vintage.version>4.12.0-M2</junit.vintage.version>
<junit.platform.version>1.0.0-M2</junit.platform.version>
```

to

```
<junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0-M3</junit.jupiter.version>
<junit.vintage.version>4.12.0-M3</junit.vintage.version>
<junit.platform.version>1.0.0-M3</junit.platform.version>
```

allowed Maven to recognize the @Tag.