# JUnit 5 Testfactory

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, java-8, junit5

I came across a scenario, where I had to initialize a Testcase

```
@Test
public void foo() {
}
```

so that Maven recognizes my TestFactory

```
@TestFactory
public Stream<DynamicTest> dynamicTestsFromStream() throws IOException{ 
...
}
```

After some research I came across this:

> In contrast to @Test methods, a @TestFactory method is not itself a test case but rather a factory for test cases. Thus, a dynamic test is the product of a factory.
>   http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests

Is there a way to force a TestFactory run without any @Test methods in my Test class, because this way it is "faking" my Jenkins build process since I'll always have +1 Test run and +1 Successful Test.

**EDIT:**

This problem occures when running `mvn test` in the maven project from the cmd console.

My dependencies are:

```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefireprovider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0-M1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>4.12.0-M1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.0-M1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
```

**SUMMARY**

Upgrading my Maven JUnit Engines to M3 solved the problem.

Comment: I think this was a bug a while ago. Can you include the JUnit versions you are using and whether this problem occurs in an IDE or build system (which?).

Comment: `org.junit.platform(1.0.0-M1)`, `org.junit.vintage(4.12.0-M1)`,`org.junit.jupiter(5.0.0-M1)`

Occures at `mvn test` at cmd console.

Comment: Please upgrade to M3. That fixed the problems at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808861/how-to-use-junit-5-tag-with-intellij-and-maven