# How to specify which @Tag should be used for JUnit in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, tags, junit5

Is there a way to specify from the build in JUnit5 Runner of IntelliJ that only test methods with specific @Tag should be tested (or the opposite, that all tests except those with a specific @Tag, should be executed)?

I know how to do it with maven, but is it possible with just the IntelliJ UI?

Best regards,
Dieter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163481 fixed, it is now possible since IJ 2018.1 -- for details see @Nicolau 's answer.

Answer (score 17):

Now it is possible with Intellij IDEA 2018.1:

[image]

See [Tag Expressions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-tag-expressions) to select which tests to execute according with their tagging.

---

Also, you can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51092232/4071001) for details on how to achieve the same goal using `maven-surefire-plugin`.