# JUnit 5 test suite choose test methods

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

Having some test classes with `Junit 5` and Spring Boot REST controller testing.

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestClassA {
   @Autowired
   private MockMvc mockMvc;

   @Test
   @WithMockUser
   public void testMethod1() {
   ...
   }

   @Test
   @WithMockUser
   public void testMethod2() {
   ...
   }

   // more test methods
}

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestClassB {
   @Autowired
   private MockMvc mockMvc;

   @Test
   @WithMockUser
   public void testMethod1() {
   ...
   }

   // more test methods

   @Test
   @WithMockUser
   public void testMethodX() {
      // requires that TestClassA.testMethod2()
      // must be run first
   }
}
```

The test classes run, each testing a specific REST controller, but how to achieve a new test method `TestClassB.testMethodX()`?

I thought to create a test suite in JUnit 5 and specify which test methods to run, also in order:

```
1. run TestClassA.testMethod2()

2. run TestClassB.testMethodX()
```

I know about two annotations:
- `@SelectPackages`
- `@SelectClasses`

But selecting specific test methods not possible?
Is this achievable with `JUnit 5`?

Comment: Is it really important to choose an order of the test methods? I would suggest to build your test methods to run without a fix order. In order to choose methods to run, you could use the `@Tag` annotation. Did you hear about that?

Comment: Tag annotation on TestClassA.testMethod2() and on TestClassB.testMethodX(), in the test suite specifying that methods with that specific tag shall be run? Don't know about the Tag annotation so far, have to check the API. Sometimes there must be an ordering, if an object isn't created first, other logic cannot access it or modify it, etc.

Comment: If Tag annotation is applied on relevant test methods, and the test suite includes them, how to apply specific ordering on those test methods to be run accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot answer both of your questions, but at least I can give you a hint on how to choose a set of test methods which should be run.

For my understanding unit/integration tests should not rely on a specific order to pass successfully. Is it really necessary, or can you realize important requirements for tasks using things like `@Before` annotations?

In my setup, I run *Spring Boot* with *Gradle*.

### JUnit Tags & Filtering

JUnit 5 allows to add tag(s) to your test methods, using the `@Tag` annotation. With this feature it is possible to filter your test methods on test execution. Have a look at [baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-filtering-tests) for a short tutorial.

### Tag your test methods

Mark your test methods with a tag fitting to your purpose, like this.

```java
   @Test
   @Tag("IntegrationTest")
   public void testMethod1() {
   ...
   }

   // more test methods

   @Test
   @Tag("UnitTest")
   public void testMethodX() {
   ...
   }
```

### Run tagged methods

#### Run tagged methods using IntelliJ

If you use the IntelliJ IDE, it is rather simple to run test methods with specific tags. See [jetbrains.com docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-junit.html) or [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44294074/how-to-specify-which-tag-should-be-used-for-junit-in-intellij-idea).

- `Run` -> `Edit Configurations...` -> `+` (Add new configuration) -> `JUnit`
- As `Test kinds` choose `Tags`
- Insert your desired tag at `Tag expression`

[image: IntelliJ]

#### Run tagged methods using Gradle

In case you want to run your test methods for instance in a continuous integration pipeline you probably run the tests using Gradle or Maven. For Gradle I can also show you a possibility to run methods with specific tags.

**Open `build.gradle`** 
For dependencies you probably already have integrated the JUnit 5 framework, similar to this:

```
dependencies {
    // [...]
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    // [...]
}
```

You also should have a `test` task.

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The command `$ gradlew test` would now run **all** defined test methods. So, to run just a specific set of methods, I suggest to create [custom tasks](https://mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-how-to-exclude-some-tests/), like this.

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

task unitTests(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags 'UnitTest'
    }
}

task integrationTests(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags 'IntegrationTest'
    }
}
```

After that, you are able run the tasks on the command line interface, e.g.: `$ gradlew unitTests` and it would just run the tasks you defined in your custom task.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I use Maven as build management tool. Yes, the ordering is necessary, because TestClassA.testMethod2() tests a REST controller and creates a specific object, or for simplicity let's assume a database entry. That object/entry must exist, before TestClassB.testMethodX() accesses it, otherwise the test method makes no sense. Ordering is necessary for example, first the database has to be populated with data (done by one class or REST controller), afterwards other classes or REST controllers can use the data from the database. It must be that kind of ordering.

Comment: Also, I have two different test classes, each testing a specific REST controller, each of the provided request methods given. Now I need something (maybe a test suite, so called) which runs one method from TestClassA and one method from TestClassB, in order.

Comment: Ordering is a feature in Junit 5: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-execution-order

But how does it work across test classes, in a test suite.

Comment: I get your point, and I'm not sure how to use the ordering feature across different test classes. But the documentation also says *"Although true unit tests typically should not rely on the order in which they are executed [...]"* and I would try to keep it that way. For cases when your database needs specific data for a test, generate it with an initializer method with `@BeforeEach` annotation. Then your `@Test` method is not dependent on further methods. Would that be a possibility for you? We could add this to the answer.

Comment: Your answer is correct, it answers my initial question. Although in a second thought I need an ordering in the test suite.