# Running JUnit Tests in IntelliJ with category annotations

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I am trying to run all tests with the annotation `@FastTests` in a module **using IntelliJ** . I can run all tests in the module using the `JUnit` configuration with the test kind `All In Package` and the relevant package name.

When I try to run a single category by choosing the `Category` test kind JUnit configuration and choose `Search For Tests: Across Module Dependencies` or `Search for Tests: In Single module` I get `No Tests were found`

**Is there a way to run JUnit tests with annotated with a single category in intellij?**

Cheers

Comment: Did you find the solution? Do you need any more help with this?

Answer (score 7):

This works for me using Intellij IDEA 2018.1:

[image]

with category marker defined as interface:

```
public interface FastTests { /* category marker */ }
```

and test class or method annotated like this:

```
import cu.nicolau.sircap.nomencladores.FastTests;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;

public class NomencladorServiceImplTest {    
    @Test
    @Category(FastTests.class)
    public void categoryTest() {
        ...
    }    
}
```

---

With [JUnit 5](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/), the `@Category` annotation gets replaced with the more flexible `@Tag` annotation.

If you consider [migrating](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-tips) to JUnit 5, [this blog](http://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-migration) can be a good place to start. Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50958900/4071001) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51092232/4071001) answer can show you how to filter the tests execution based on their tags, using Intellij IDEA or Maven.